# How to make text, number and date html input fields support Ctrl+Z (undo) in a consistent fashion?

Tags: javascript, html

The text input field appears to support the Ctrl+Z (undo) fully.

The number and date input field only supports it, if the value has been typed into the field in question. If, however, it was selected by means of the associated helper control (i.e. the range control for the number fields and the calendar control for the date fields), then Ctrl+Z does not work.

Can anyone advice how to make the number and date fields support Ctrl+Z no matter how the value is entered by the user?

Thanks.

P.S.

I am currently using jquery and chrome.

**EDIT1**

I am using `<input type='number' ...` and `<input type='date' ...` It is entirely possible that I should use something else (what?)

**EDIT2**

I am talking about interactive actions only, not script based changes.

Comment: Please post some code. Are you using HTML5 `<input type=number>` etc. or jQuery tools (which?) for input or both?

Comment: Added the missing information.

Comment: Personally I'm not sure this is a great move. Firstly it's unprecedented; I cannot think of any other non-typing action a user can do in a browser that can be undone with CTRL+Z (e.g. selection from dropdowns, which your case is similar to). Secondly it would override (or conflict with) in-built browser functionality. In Opera, for example, CTRL+Z, when pressed outside of a text field, re-opens the last-closed tab.

Comment: It is kinda inconsistent, that if I type in a number field, then I can undo it, but if I select from the range control - then I do not. Don't you think so?

Comment: I see where you're coming from, but the convention - at least in a browser - is that CTRL+Z is for what has been typed, not what has been invoked by other means. As such, you could also argue that your userbase will not be expecting (or therefore using) such functionality should you provide it.

Comment: @mark What browser do you use? In Chrome `text` does not fully support `Ctrl` + `z`. In FF also. I.e. if I change the value of the text-input with script `Ctrl` + `z` won't help

Comment: I do not want script. I am talking about interactive actions only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undo is a weak spot in HTML5 applications. There is no simple solution because undo is ultimately application dependent (just like in desktop apps).

See this question for some solutions: [Implementing undo in a web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386743/implementing-undo-in-a-web-app)